# Exit main thread when condition or child threads exits

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

My C program is composed by two threads, started by the `main` thread. When the program starts, the `main` creates two threads using `pthread_create`. These threads, `th1` and `th2`, performs some sum/subtract operations on a global int variable `S`.

`th1` and `th2` can exit at some point, depending on certain conditions.

The thread `main` starts `th1` and `th2`, then should wait and exit depending on

1. a condition: `S` reaches a value greater than a number
2. both `th1` and `th2` exited

Whatever condition comes first, `main` will exit and print out S. **What is the correct approach to write the exit condition of the main?**

Note this is an University exercise, therefore the solution should be reasonable simple, and based on a limited set of C libraries, including `pthread.h`.

---

I could not use `pthread_join` on `th1` and `th2` because the number could pass the threshold (condition 1) before the child threads would exit. **Is there a way to check in `main` if child threads are not running anymore?**

My solution uses a `pthread_cond_t` in the `main`. The logical check of the condition are the number of running threads and the integer comparison. When a thread is created, I register it (incrementing the `threads` counter). When it exits, I deregister it. All changes are wrapped in a mutex.

```
int main() {
  pthread_t th1, th2;
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&run, NULL);
  srand(time(NULL));
  int ret;

  // ...

  if (pthread_create(&th1, NULL, alpha, NULL) == 0) {
    thread_register();
  }
  if (pthread_create(&th2, NULL, beta, NULL) == 0) {
    thread_register();
  }

  for (;;) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(threads > 0 && S < 1000) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&run, &mutex);
    }
    pthread_cancel(th1);
    pthread_cancel(th2);
    break;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Child threads sends a `pthread_cond_signal` to wake up `main` when either they are shutting down or they change `S`.

In this way, every time `main` wakes up, it can check if child threads are gone (`threads == 0` or `S <` threshold).

Comment: Only thing I see wrong with what you have is that the only thing the `for` loop will ever accomplish is skipping the `pthread_mutex_unlock` call, which is probably not what you want, but also likely doesn't matter since you're about to exit the process.  Are you seeing a problem / undesirable behavior?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good call. The break was added after a small refactoring, I didn't notice it. Your feedback definitely makes sense.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland No, the program works as expected. It just feels quite complicated, because of all the signal/wait calls I had to introduce to synchronize the processes. I was surprised that such as reasonable simple  program could require such implementation effort (such as registering/deregistering threads manually, etc).

Comment: The thread registration/count part could be simplified to two decrement operations if you can guarantee both operations are atomic.  If using C11/C++11 or later, there are language std features for this (`atomic_fetch_add` / `atomic_fetch_sub`).  If older version of the language, you can use compiler built-ins (e.g. GCC's `__sync_fetch_and_add`)

Comment: @BrianMcFarland feel free to post your comments as reply, so that I can accept it.